# Remove unwanted symbols using regex in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that contains a list for each rows. I want to remove unwanted symbols in my dataset and replace the data that contains [] with none. But, the coding is not working.

[image: The example of the dataset]

Here the coding for the data cleaning.

```
def clean_data(data):
    cleaned_data = []

    for item in data:
        cleaned_item = {}
        for key, value in item.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                # Replace '[]' with 'None'
                value = value.replace('[]', 'None')
                # Convert to lowercase
                value = value.lower()
                # Remove unwanted characters
                value = re.sub(r'[\[\]{}\'"]', '', value)  # Update the regular expression
            cleaned_item[key] = value
        cleaned_data.append(cleaned_item)

    return cleaned_data
```

After run the coding, the symbol is still not being removed.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["'[{A}', '[{B}]'", "'[{C}', '[{D}]'"], columns=['col1'])
```

`df`

```
    col1
0   '[{A}', '[{B}]'
1   '[{C}', '[{D}]'
```

**Code**

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r"[\[\]{}\']", "", regex=True)
```

`df`

```
    col1
0   A, B
1   C, D
```